# Web Api: Pass an empty parameter in a query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for a proper way to handle empty parameters in a query string. Web Api does not accept query strings as "?id=1&category=", which seems reasonable, but I need to handle this case.

The quick and dirty solution is to use a custom value which will be interpreted on the server side (say "(empty)" for example) but I'm not satisfied with it...

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I have dealt with this in the past is to make a class to hold your paramaters and then use to ModelBinder attribute to bind your query parameters to the class properties.

So your class would look something like this:

```
public class QueryParams
{
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

And the method in your api controller would look like this:

```
public objectToReturn Get([ModelBinder] QueryParams)
{
    //code here
}
```

This way if one of the parameters in the query string has no value it will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. However, this implies that I interpret a null value for my category as an empty string in my controller. I wish "category=" would be interpreted as string empty, and the absence of this parameter in my query string as null.

Comment: A way to get around this would be to add a constructor to the QueryParams class and then use it to assign `string.empty` to the Category property.

Comment: This is the way I'm dealing with a similar situation in a resource planning app where I have a customized DateTime that can be a straight datetime or a set of keywords like "On Hold" or a blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this attribute to achieve what you want.

```
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
```

If "category" is missing then it will be null.
Otherwise, if "category=" or "category=  " then will be an empty string or whitespace.

Comment: Excellent--this is exactly what I've been looking for